# Inserting SQL statement into PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to insert an SQL statment into a variable. The statement contains keywords entered by the user in a search bar. However, for some reason I can keep getting the error "Trying to get the property of non-object". Below is my code:

```
public function searchTable() {                  
      $sql = "SELECT grades_eng.Grade, domain_math_eng.Domain, cluster_eng.Cluster, math_standards_eng.Standard FROM ".$this->standardsTable." 
              WHERE Standard LIKE '%".$this->keyword." %'
              INNER JOIN grades_eng ON math_standards_eng.Grade_Id = grades_eng.Id 
              INNER JOIN domain_math_eng ON math_standards_eng.Domain_Math_Eng_Id = domain_math_eng.Id
              INNER JOIN cluster_eng ON math_standards_eng.Cluster_Eng_Id = cluster_eng.Id";

      $results = $this->conn->query($sql);
      //returns array
      return $results;
      }
```

The code for the object being used:

```
$search = new SearchResult($conn, $subject, $keyword);
$queryResults = $search->searchTable();
$search->displayResults($queryResults);
```

Im confident is my sql query that's causing the error because when I use the following code, it displays results :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->standardsTable." WHERE Standard LIKE '%".$this->keyword."%' ";
$results = $this->conn->query($sql);
```

Im Trying to display the same results but replace the IDs with actual text. The query does work when I run it in MySql.

P.S Still working on learning to use Aliases so I apologize in advance.

Comment: You should use parameterized queries, and use error reporting so the driver tells you what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that the "Where" keyword was suppose to go towards the end. Lesson learned!

```
$sql = "SELECT grades_eng.Grade, domain_math_eng.Domain, cluster_eng.Cluster, math_standards_eng.Standard FROM ".$this->standardsTable." 
      INNER JOIN grades_eng ON math_standards_eng.Grade_Id = grades_eng.Id 
      INNER JOIN domain_math_eng ON math_standards_eng.Domain_Math_Eng_Id = domain_math_eng.Id
      INNER JOIN cluster_eng ON math_standards_eng.Cluster_Eng_Id = cluster_eng.Id
      WHERE Standard LIKE '%".$this->keyword."%' ";
```